# Excel merge two tables, repeating 2nd table lookup row

Tags: excel

I have two Excel Tables with a 'lookup' column to merge against. I want to merge to a new table with all the lookup values expanded.  If I were doing this in python or some such, the pseudo-code would be something like:

```
for unique day in Tbl1
  row1 = day
  row2 = ""
  for event in Tbl1 day
    v = event's lookup value in Tbl2
    row1 += event + (len(v) - 1) blank columns
    row2 += v
  print(row1)
  print(row2)
```

I'd like to avoid VBA, but *would* like to use new dynamic array functions (preferred) or power query (if necessary), but I can't figure out how to get the repeat to happen. The power query merges I've tried aren't complete.

The original data (where I've used abbreviations for my real data), has a number of events per day. The 'lookup' column shows the different levels of that event for that day.

**Tbl1**

| day | event | lookup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Re | eoni2 |
| 1 | Gr | eoni1 |
| 1 | We | eoni1 |
| 2 | Tn | eoneonii2 |
| 2 | Ga | eon1 |
| 2 | Gr | eoni1 |

**Tbl2**

| lookup | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| eeononii | E | E | O | N | O | N | I | I |
| eon1 | E | O | N |  |  |  |  |  |
| eoneonii2 | E | O | N | E | O | N | I | I |
| eoni1 | E | O | N | I |  |  |  |  |
| eoni2 | E | E | O | O | N | N | I | I |

- **Tbl1**

  - Data will change: number of events per day, event value, what lookup value might be for an event.
  - The 'event' may or may not repeat from one day to the next, but will be unique within a day.
  - Order (top to bottom) should be maintained in resulting merge (left to right).
  - Max number of days = 3.
- **Tbl2**

  - generally static and top to bottom order can be changed if needed.
  - may contain entries that are not used by Tbl1.
  - min of 3 and max of 8 values per row.
- **Tbl3** output

  - ideally, the 'event' name would *not* repeat, as shown below, but can if it keeps formula cleaner.
  - the number of columns for each day in output Tbl3 may not be the same, as shown, e.g. day 1 rows have 16 and day 2 rows have 15 here.

The output I want:

**Tbl3**

| day | e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | e5 | e6 | e7 | e8 | e9 | e10 | e11 | e12 | e13 | e14 | e15 | e16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Re |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Gr |  |  |  | We |  |  |  |
|  | E | E | O | O | N | N | I | I | E | O | N | I | E | O | N | I |
| 2 | Tn |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Ga |  |  | Gr |  |  |  |  |
|  | E | O | N | E | O | N | I | I | E | O | N | E | O | N | I |  |

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Read in both tables
//Edit Source and Source1 lines to reflect your actual table names
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"day", Int64.Type}, {"event", type text}, {"lookup", type text}}),

    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source1), each {_, type text})),

//Join the two tables based on the lookup column
//then remove that column
    #"Join Tables" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type","lookup", #"Changed Type1","lookup", "joined"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Join Tables",{"lookup"}),

//Add index column to maintain original Event order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Expand the joined table and remove the Index column
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index", "joined", {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded joined",{"Index"}),

//Unpivot all the "value" columns
//Then remove the "Attribute" column (the previous column Headers)
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns2", {"day", "event"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),   

//Group by "day"
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"day"}, {
        {"event & value", (t)=> let 
            remDay = Table.RemoveColumns(t,"day"),
            //replace all except first event of a type with null
            nullEvents = List.Accumulate(t[event],{}, (state,current)=>
                if state = {} then {current} 
                else if List.Contains(state,current) then state & {null}
                else state & {current}),

            //then create new table and Transpose to get final format    
            newTable = Table.Transpose(Table.FromColumns(
                {nullEvents, t[Value]}            
                ))
        in 
            newTable}
        }),

    //Calculate number of columns for creating column names
    numCols = List.Max(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[#"event & value"], each Table.ColumnCount(_))),

    //expand the grouped columns and set the appropriate names
    #"Expanded event & value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "event & value",
        List.Transform(List.Numbers(1,numCols), each "Column" & Text.From(_)),
        List.Transform(List.Numbers(1,numCols), each "e" & Text.From(_))),

    //Replace alternate "day" with null
    replaceWithNulls = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.Accumulate(#"Expanded event & value"[day], {}, (state,current)=> 
            if Number.IsOdd(List.Count(state)) 
            then state & {null} else state & {current})} & 
            Table.ToColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded event & value","day")),
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded event & value")
            ),


    //set the data types
    typeit = Table.TransformColumnTypes(replaceWithNulls, 
        {{"day", Int64.Type}} & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(replaceWithNulls),1), each {_, type text}))
in
    typeit
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks for **completely** solving the problem.  And your code comments give me insight into how I might use this to figure out more problems as a not-yet-power-user of Excel.